# Testing a List "Searchable" Controller

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, test-data-isolation, test-setup

Will someone please explain, or correct, my testing logic for the following code? The first image is the test, and second image is the code.

**Here's the test**

[image]

**Here's the code**

[image]

**Here's the code again, but not in image form**

```
@isTest <br>
private class SearchableListController_Test {
    static testMethod void SearchableListController_Test(){
      SearchableListController SC = new SearchableListController();
      sc.linkVar = [SELECT id, Document_Name__c FROM Link__c WHERE document_name__c like 'Police' LIMIT 1];
        sc.doQuery();
        sc.toLaserfiche();
    Link__c[] test1 = [SELECT Document_Name__c FROM Link__c];
        Link__c test2 = test1[0];
      System.assertEquals(1, test1.size());
      System.assertEquals(test1, sc.linkVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have 86% coverage (13/15 lines), so what lines aren't covered that you're concerned about?

Comment: I believe the test is failing... or maybe I'm reading the little red x's wrong at the bottom-left of the test screen.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Didn't see that, only saw the lines of coverage.  One thing I did notice, but didn't comment on because I saw the coverage is that I don't see where you're creating test data but perhaps you're doing that in a common test data creation method above what's visible in your screen capture? If it's failing, you need to look at the debug logs to understand why.

Comment: Thank you. But, yeah, all that is shown is the complete code. The stuff above is just a comment block that briefly describes what this test is for. I'll go to the logs and see what I can find there. Meanwhile, if someone spots something that'll help solve this conundrum, please feel free to comment.

Comment: You can't query data that doesn't exist and expect to return results. You'll need to either use "SeeAllData" or load static test data to query on during your test.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I added the code (text) up above,  and removed the comments. Can you demonstrate your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the test that worked. It appears that I was on the right track in the beginning.

@isTest
private class SearchableListController_Test {

```
static testMethod void SearchableListController_Test(){

SearchableListController SC = new SearchableListController();

    sc.linkVar = [SELECT id, Document_Name__c
                  FROM Link__c
                  WHERE document_name__c like 'police'
                  LIMIT 1];

insert(sc.linkVar);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any documents in `Link__c WHERE document_name__c like 'Police'`, your query for `sc.linkVar` won't return any results.

You need to insert at least one `document_name__c` in `Link__c` that has a name like 'Police' for you to query on in order for your query to return any results and your test class to pass.